# 0x82bc0005 error with Xbox Games

Tags: windows-8, connection

I'm using Windows 8 and its app Xbox Games from quite some time. But over the past few days I am unable to sign in and wasn't getting any error code. Then today when I fired up Wordament, I got this error code `0x82bc0005`. How to fix this?

Comment: Pure a Microsoft response on another website, from somebody with a similar proble, it sounds like you ned to reset Windows 8

Comment: Will a refresh do? Or I have to do a full reset? And whats the error?

Comment: Try a refresh first, if that doesn't work, do a full a reset.  Are you really asking me what the error was?  You posted it.

Comment: I did a refresh. Its fine now. I wanted to know what the error means

Comment: The only way I know how to find that information out is Microsoft support forum website or look at the Microsoft support articles. But my limited research didn't bring up a specific reason for the error which means its a generic error.  If you want to know more it will take more research on your part.

Comment: Support articles haven't helped. Refresh borked the PC. So, I had to backup the files and did a reset. Just want to know what error it is to avoid in the future

Comment: Your best hope is to ask Microsoft here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network connection for Metro apps got borked somewhere. A refresh helped. Weirdly enough, the error is not documented anywhere.

Comment: I've run into this myself on three different occasions; I use my laptop (and, I have to admit, play the Daily Challenges) from various wireless networks all over the place - home, clients' offices, Starbucks, Coffee Bean & Tea Leaf...  Anyway, each time I've run into code 0x82bc0005 it's been on a coffee-shop WiFi network, and it's been resolved by going home + a reboot.

Comment: For me, a reboot didn't help. I use the internet at home and at college through a proxy server

Comment: Well, I didn't necessarily think it would be a universal solution, but what I was getting at was: this error (whatever its actual specific meaning) is the Xbox client throwing up its hands and saying "Dude.  Your network... what is this I don't even..."  or words to that effect.  I have no idea why it's so much more fragile than other applications - each time I've had the error, I was able to use Firefox and Chrome to access GMail, YouTube, etc. - but then it's a proprietary network application, so it's not a huge surprise.

Comment: Not just Xbox,  I have noticed that Metro apps in general are very fragile with respect to networks and all.

Comment: "I have noticed that Metro apps in general are **useless**."  Fixed that for you.  ;)

Comment: Ah well. To each his own